# Why DataTemplate's Trigger's Setter.TargetName property cannot find target with Property="Background", but can with Property="Panel.Background"

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, datatemplate

I'm implementing a template for ListBox's ItemTemplate and I have a quite simple compilation error, but I can't figure out what is the reason behind it. I'd like to know why there's this difference between `Property="Panel.Background"` and `Property="Background"`. The first variant gives no error and compiles well, while the latter produces compilation error:

> Error  MC4111  Cannot find the Trigger target 'ContentBorder'.  (The target must appear before any Setters, Triggers, or Conditions that use it.)

Why DataTemplate's Trigger's Setter.TargetName property cannot find target with `Property="Background"`, but can with `Property="Panel.Background"`? I did not change the position of the trigger in the VisualTree (as in: I did not move the trigger further down the tree).

Sorry if this question was already answered elsewhere; I did my reasearch, but failed finding any answer related specifically to this question and result that I came up with.

Below is the complete XAML to reproduce this case.

````
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel  />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="ContentBorder" Value="DarkTurquoise" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="10" x:Name="ContentBorder">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Gray"/>
                                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Black"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Black"/>
                                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Gray"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <ResourceDictionary>
                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </ResourceDictionary>
                            </Grid.Resources>
                        
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="Items" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="Items" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding StartTime, StringFormat={}Start time: {0:dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss}}" />
                            <TextBlock
                                Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding SportTypeId, Converter={x:Static Converters:SportTypeCodeToTextConverter.Instance}}"
                                FontWeight="Bold" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Distance, StringFormat={}Distance: {0}}" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Duration, StringFormat={}Duration: {0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember, the order of specifying the template and its triggers matters.
Try this:

```
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="10" x:Name="ContentBorder">
            <!--Filling in the template-->
        </Border>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkTurquoise" TargetName="ContentBorder"/>
            </Trigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
```

And to clarify, just in case, Border inherits Background from Control.
Therefore, the full name of the property is Control.Background, but not Panel.Background.

Comment: From what I've checked just now, Border inherits Decorator class; the Background property is not inherited, it is a property defined within Border class.
Thanks for the answer, I've accepted it - it is the solution. I actually thought this compilation error was related to the visual tree, not the order of elements defined in XAML. Thanks!

Comment: "> From what I've checked just now, Border inherits Decorator class "  
You're right.
I wrote without checking.
Now I looked at the sources - Border uses exactly `Panel.BackgroundProperty`.